# How to properly remove carriage return in python while using with dictwriter (newline='' does not help)

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a simple pythono code that parses json file and returns it as dictionary. I have to write this in to CSV file but only with the LF as a line terminator. However, Carriage return appears anyway even using newline=''. wb mode is not an option as i receive this error

**return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

My code for CSV writing:

```
with open(statsFilePath,'w+', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header , delimiter = '|')
  for row in result:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

And here is the screenshot of what i see in Notepad++

[image: crLf]

**UPDATE, SOLVED**

The DictWriter used the default line terminator. Changing the code to this, solved the issue:

```
with open(statsFilePath,'w+', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header , delimiter = '|', lineterminator="\n")
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv `Dialect` decides which line terminator to use and [by default it is `\r\n`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator).

You need to specify `lineterminator` when defining the writer:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header , delimiter = '|', lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but posted just a minute after i found it, Thank You anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open(statsFilePath,'w+', newline='\n', encoding='utf8') as f:
```

Please remember that `LF` is probably not what you are looking for. You are looking for `CR` as your line separator (UNIX's default).

Comment: Unfortunately, tried \n as well and got the same result

Comment: Note that a value of `\n` does **not** mean that only LF will be used in the output. It is equivalent to just the empty string `''` and it means that *no translation is performed*. This means that if the strings you write contain `\r\n` then it will write `\r\n` instead of `\n`. It is possible that `DictWriter` uses `os.linesep` by default which would cause what the OP is describing?

Comment: BTW: CR is not used by linux nor by MacOS. They both use LF i.e. `\n`

Comment: You are right, DictWriter used default linesep, just found that I can change it using "lineterminator". Thank You

Comment: @AlexShangin I just found that out too and took the time to post an answer. Why did you accept an answer that was not useful in this situation?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I thought that comment was written by Pablo, my bad, fixed.